# Java math.pow, get '^' to be like 4^3 <=> math.pow(4,3)

Tags: java, int, double, pow

I have a problem with a school project, where I need some help...
The problem is, that I can't figure out how to use the `Math.pow` properly, so I can say like (1/(1+x^5)), and it will calculate the x^5 as `math.pow(x,5)`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= (n/2)-1; i++) {
    xi = a + i*h;
    s1 += f(numF, xi);
}
```

Here `numF` is (1/(1+x^5)).

This is an integral calculator, so it should be like (1/(1+x^xi)).
And `numF` is from a TextField, so it not always the same, so it's when `^` is used, it shall do the calculation

This is how it looks in full

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {
    public JButton CalcButton;
    public JTextField InputA;
    public JTextField InputB;
    public JTextField InputN;
    public JTextField InputF;
    public JTextField OutputAnswer;
    public JLabel OutputAnswerLabel;
    public JLabel InputALabel;
    public JLabel InputBLabel;
    public JLabel InputNLabel;
    public JLabel InputFLabel;

    public Calculator() {
        this.setTitle("Integral Lommeregner");
        this.setSize(280, 95);
        this.setLocation(700, 300);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) { }
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) { }
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) { }
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
                Calculator_Load();
            }
        });

        this.CalcButton = new JButton();
        this.CalcButton.setText("     Udregn     ");
        this.CalcButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CalcButton_ActionPerformed();
            }
        });

        this.InputA = new JTextField();
        this.InputA.setText("     ");
        this.InputALabel = new JLabel();
        this.InputALabel.setText("a:");

        this.InputB = new JTextField();
        this.InputB.setText("     ");
        this.InputBLabel = new JLabel();
        this.InputBLabel.setText("b:");

        this.InputN = new JTextField();
        this.InputN.setText("     ");
        this.InputNLabel = new JLabel();
        this.InputNLabel.setText("n:");

        this.InputF = new JTextField();
        this.InputF.setText("                                  ");
        this.InputFLabel = new JLabel();
        this.InputFLabel.setText("F(x)=");

        this.OutputAnswer = new JTextField();
        this.OutputAnswer.setText("                                 ");
        this.OutputAnswer.setEditable(false);
        this.OutputAnswerLabel = new JLabel();
        this.OutputAnswerLabel.setText("Areal:");

        add(InputALabel);
        add(InputA);
        add(InputBLabel);
        add(InputB);
        add(InputNLabel);
        add(InputN);
        add(InputFLabel);
        add(InputF);
        add(CalcButton);
        add(OutputAnswerLabel);
        add(OutputAnswer);
    }

    private void Calculator_Load() {
        InputA.setText("");
        InputB.setText("");
        InputN.setText("");
        InputF.setText("");
        OutputAnswer.setText("");
    }

    private void CalcButton_ActionPerformed() {
        try {
            int a, b, numF, n;
            double h, xi, xj, s1, s2, integral;
            a = Integer.parseInt(InputA.getText());
            do {
                b = Integer.parseInt(InputB.getText());
            }
            while (b <= a);
            n = Integer.parseInt(InputN.getText());
            numF = Integer.parseInt(InputF.getText());
            h = (double) (b - a) / n;
            for (int i = 1; i <= (n / 2) - 1; i++) {
                xi = a + i * h;
                s1 += f(numF, xi);
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= (n / 2); j++) {
                xj = a + j * h;
                s2 += 2;
            }
            integral = (h / 3) * 2;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post all your code? What's a, numF, h,n etc?

Comment: `Math.pow(a,b)` calculates a^b, so if you want to compute something like 1/1+x^xi you should have something like `1/(1+Math.pow(x,xi))`. Also becareful that `Math.pow` computes on `double`s not `int`egers. You must also convert your `numF` (a `String`) to a `double` with something like `Double.parseDouble(numF)`.

Comment: I see, but the problem is, that it shall not only be (1/(1+x^xi)), i can also be a random text, like (x4)+5

Answer (score 1):

You really seem to be asking how to parse and evaluate an arithmetical expression provided in String form.

This is a tricky problem for beginners, but there are two "relatively easy" ways to approach this:

1. Read up on the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) and apply that to your expression language.
2. Develop a *grammar* for your expression language and use a parser generator (Antlr, javacc, etc) to generate a parser and lexer, with the expression evaluation logic embedded in the parser actions.  (Expression parsing is a common tutorial topic in a PGS's documentation set.)